# Does a "leading-slash"(root) URL within a subdomain resolve to the TLD, or the subdomain?

Tags: html, hyperlink, subdomain

We're wanting to migrate an old version of a site to a `legacy.*.com` subdomain, hoping this will quickly solve the issues of all the `/.../...` links used in the old site.

E.g. Would the link `/abc.html` on the `legacy.*.com` subdomain resolve to `legacy.*.com/abc.html`, or `http://*.com/abc.html`?

Comment: Off-hand, I'm not wholly sure (I can see arguments for it working either way), why don't you try it, and find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the beginning slash makes the link relative to the FQDN of the site. So for `http://domain.tld` a link with a target of `/abc.html` will resolve to `http://domain.tld/abc.html`. If that same site was moved to `http://legacy.domain.tld` the same link will resolve to `http://legacy.domain.tld/abc.html`.

You can easily find this out after expirimenting for 5mins. Don't be afraid to just try it out first instead of posting a question :)

Comment: Thanks @chris, an unusual routing setup left me without confidence in my tests, but hopefully others find this helpful!

Comment: I have found this helpful! I'm now curious about how to access the root domain, though.

Answer (score 0):

it will resolve to legacy.yoursite.com unless your webserver redirects it for some reason. Generally though the path is defined by your webserver and the domains and subdomains are defined by DNS. Those are completely different systems.